# Android OS seems to be triggering an error on file download links in WebViewClient

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm running into a weird issue where certain download links on our website cause the app to call into the WebViewClient `onReceivedError` method. The app is getting a 200 response from the website and seems to be processing everything correctly in our download listeners but something between `onPageStart` and `onPageFinished` keeps triggering the call. Additionally Android documentation doesn't actually have anything for `ERR_FAILED` and I haven't found other information online that seems like it would explain it. This is the logging for the error that our app does itself.

```
Legacy Error :: onReceivedError, errorCode=-1, desc=net::ERR_FAILED
```

This is the stack trace I can get from the debugger

```
onReceivedError:487, ****WebViewClient (com.****.webview)
handleMessage:128, on
dispatchMessage:107, Handler (android.os)
loop:237, Looper (android.os)
main:7762, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:493, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:1047, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

It's frustrating because the download does happen regardless and the only solution I've been able to come up with is just special casing the "failing" urls so that we don't actually throw an exception when the app seems to behave perfectly fine if it just gets to keep going. This obviously runs into issues as more of these links are introduced as it's a reactive solution instead of a proactive one and not all download links run into this problem just a few. Another thing that's strange is that this doesn't get triggered in an emulator meaning there's some difference on a real device that causes the bug.

Comment: same problem with me.is there any solution?

Comment: is there any solution found?

Comment: @NiteshKhosla I didn't find a solution so we ended up just trapping the error for the use case and avoiding calling into the recovery steps.

Comment: Apparently a bug in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1048335